# No result in my result view of Quick watch but the result is under non-public members

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

in my query when i see quick watch, under the result it returns no result but when go through Non-Public members under source and result in view I see all my results,how can i access to them? and why its like this?im using PostgreSQL for my database

```
 var test = (from t in db.v_vpn_gateway.AsEnumerable()
                    where t.turbine_id.ToString() == id
                    select new TurbineDvce
                    {
                        Comments = "VPN Gateway",
                        Description = string.Empty,
                        DeviceIP = t.vpn_gateway.ToString(),
                        DeviceType = t.device_type,
                        FirmwareVersion = string.Empty,
                        Model = t.model,
                        Password = string.Empty,
                        Phone = string.Empty,
                        Producer = t.producer,
                        PublicIP = t.vpn_public_ip.ToString(),
                        TurbineId = t.turbine_id.ToString(),
                        Username = string.Empty
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to "Hydrate" the result. The way Linq works with Lazy Evaluation, really you are just getting a place holder back for the `test` variable, and the actual query will run when the test variable is used by other code. Since you have a "where" clause, you should be expecting back an IEnumerable, so you can add `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to the end of your query, which will force the query to run and store the list or array in your `test` variable. That should give you access to that data right after the query runs.